# Optional parameter in select 1=1

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql, where-clause

I have an optional parameter in my function, and I want to display all records if it's not specified and if yes only the record with the specified id. I tried this code but it doesn't work. The principal is if the P_PC_ID is in the table so PC_ID=P_PC_ID will be displayed, and if P_PC_ID is empty & need to have 1=1

```
SELECT PC_ID,CLIENT_NUMBER,TRANSACTION_DATE,AMOUNT FROM history_table
WHERE  NVL(NVL(PC_ID,P_PC_ID),'X') = NVL(P_PC_ID,'X')
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the good answer by GMB, If you want to use the `NVL` then you can do something like this:

```
SELECT PC_ID,CLIENT_NUMBER,TRANSACTION_DATE,AMOUNT 
  FROM history_table
 WHERE NVL(P_PC_ID, PC_ID) = PC_ID
```

If `P_PC_ID` is null then it will compare `PC_ID` with `PC_ID`, which will be always true.

Comment: I used this one & works like a charm thanks ! i added a trim : NVL(TRIM(P_PC_ID), PC_ID) = PC_ID

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend boolean logic instead of this nested `NVL()`s:

```
select pc_id, client_number, transaction_date, amount 
from history_table
where p_pc_id is null or p_pc_id = pc_id
```

If parameter `p_pc_id` is `null`, the first condition is true, and all rows in the table are returned; else, the first condition is false, and only rows whose `pc_id` is equal to the parameter are returned.